# How I can use One Image for all categories thumbnail

Tags: thumbnail

How I can use One Image for all categories thumbnail.

Or explaining it further, I need to set an image that will fill all the empty spaces of categories, subcategories or products where no product image  or thumbnail is uploaded

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are talking about placeholders.

### For Magento 1.X

1. Navigate to: `System > Configuration > Catalog`
   [image: How to change placeholders in Magento]
2. Upload there your 3 different images:

   - Full Size (275×275)
   - Small (150×150)
   - Thumbnail (50×50)
     [image: How to change placeholders in Magento]

### For Magento 2.x

1. Navigate to: `Stores > Settings > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog`
2. Upload there your 4 different images
   [image: How to change placeholders in Magento2]

Comment: I appreciate your answer and it really worked well. I still cannot change category thumbnails despite I have added four different type of images. Please have a look at following link, https://valuesbig.com/surgical-beauty-and-medical/cutting-instruments.html

Comment: Category or thumbnails or placeholder is not something that comes out of the box so you will need to do it. I can see in the example you provided that you are using custom code  to show a list of sub categories inside of a category. I guess you could check in your custom code something like `if category->getImage() === null or empty then show a placeholder` (a placeholder you have defined somewhere)